# После выполнения команды composer update перестает работать роутинг в Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

После выполнения команды `composer update` перестает работать роутинг в `Laravel 5`.
Делаю вот так:

```
php artisan controller:make NewController
```

Получаю: ошибку.

> There are no commands defined in the "controller" namespace.

Answer (score 1):

```
php artisan make:controller NewController
```